# Get vimeo video list api

Tags: ios, postman, vimeo-api

I have uploaded one video on vimeo account.
Tool Using - PostMan
Step1-made an POST API https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client:

```
body - {
    "grant_type":"client_credentials"   
}
Header - Authorization - Basic Base64(cid:secret)

response :
{


   "access_token": "randomValue",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": "public",
    "app": {
        "name": "AppName",
        "uri": "/apps/120663"
    }
}
```

Step 2:
Now i and making api call to get video list i.e
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos
using accesstoken as Authorization - Bearer Token

But i get response
{
    "error": "You must provide a valid authenticated access token."
}

Answer (score 0):

The format of your authorization header in the /me/videos request should be

`Authorization: Bearer {your_access_token}`

e.g.

`Authorization: Bearer abcd1234`

If you still encounter the error, your token may be incorrect and you should contact Vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Client credentials tokens are authenticated to an application, not to a user, and can only get public information from Vimeo. Because client credential (unauthenticated) tokens are not authenticated to a user, you'll receive an error when making requests to the /me endpoint path.

Generate an authenticated token by either going through the OAuth2 flow, or creating a personal access token on the app management page.

Instructions on doing that can be found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#overview

Also, see the reply here for an overview of different authentication tokens used with the Vimeo API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48772649/3704546

Comment: what i want to achieve is , i have created one vimeo account and uploaded some videos in it, and now i have iOS app in which i want to display list of videos that i uploaded , so users can see it and play.
so which endpoint should be use for that ? and how